# Como classificar letras e números em JavaScript e Lodash?

Tags: javascript

Classificar padrão de *Lodash* vem primeiro número depois letra, por exemplo:

```
const myArray = ['2', '5', '10', 'A', '1']; //sim, número String
const result = _.orderBy(myArray, item => parseInt(item), 'asc');
//['1', '2', '5', '10', 'A'];
```

Gostaria ter uma saída como esta `['A', '1', '2', '5', '10']`. Tentei outra forma, mas não saiu como resultado eu queria:

```
const result = _.orderBy(myArray, (a,b) => b - a, 'asc');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que eu saiba o `lodash` faz `sort` por chaves, mas não por conteúdo.

Para separar numeros e letras sugiro partir em duas array, organizar cada uma e depois juntá-las.

Poderia ser algo assim:

```js
function sortAlphaNum(arr) {
  const letters = [];
  const numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (arr[i].match(/\d+/)) numbers.push(arr[i]);
    else letters.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return letters.sort().concat(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));

}

const myArray = ['2', '5', 'C', '10', 'A', '1'];
console.log(sortAlphaNum(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é possível com métodos comuns de ordenação, por conta da ordenação natural dos elementos.

Se tu fizer um teste, como:

```
var lista = ['1', '4', 'C', '6', '2', 'A'];

function OrdenarArray(a, b) {
        return a > b;
    }
```

vai ter um resultado: `['1', '2', '4', '6', 'A', ...]`

Ordenei com um certo esforço:

```
var lista = ['10', '4', 'C', '6', '2', 'A'];

function OrdenarArray(a, b) {
    return a > b;
}

var lLetras = new Array();
var lNumeros = new Array();
$.each(lista, function(indice, obj) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(obj, 0)))
       lNumeros.push(Number(obj));
    else
       lLetras.push(obj);
});

lLetras = lLetras.sort(OrdenarArray);
lNumeros = lNumeros.sort(OrdenarArray);

lista = lLetras;
$.each(lNumeros, function(indice, obj) {
    lista.push(obj.toString());
});
```

Resultado final: ['A', 'C', '2', '4', ...]

Claro que deve haver melhores formas de ordenar. Ah, e usei jquery. =x

Comment: Usando `10` não funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkpscrf8/1/

Comment: Prontinho, @Sergio. https://jsfiddle.net/Lkpscrf8/5/